# Реализация «перемотки» в HTML5-видеоплеере

Tags: html, html5

Если для `src` использовать локальный файл, то плеер спокойно воспроизводит видео при смене позиции, однако если, например, я для `src` использую ссылку из Dropbox с `?dl=1` (прямая загрузка, поддерживает "докачку"), то видео воспроизводится, но смена позиции не работает. При попытке смены ползунок банально возвращается на прежнюю позицию, воспроизведение не прерывается.
Вопросы:
1. Какие условия сервера нужны для того, чтобы я имел возможность «перемотки»?
2. Как отследить запрос html5-плеера на сервер при смене позиции?

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл ответ. Сервер должен поддерживать content-range, частичные GET.
Ответ должен приходить со статусом 206 "Partial Content".
А заголовок запроса должен иметь поле Range, например Range: bytes:0-13456.